Toyota RAV4 SE Hybrid 2024 - No RPM signal from On Board Diagnostic Computer System
Today I took my car for the safety and emission inspection. Although it passed, I see the following details in the inspection report. It is important to note that I just bought the car.
Based on the information gathered during an attempt to perform an On Board Diagnostic test, NO RPM Signal was available
from the On Board Diagnostic computer system. This vehicle should produce an RPM signal from the On Board Diagnostic
computer system. This vehicle needs to have the above problem corrected prior to next year's emissions inspection.
What does this mean? Is this serious? Why should a brand new car have such an issue?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you get an OBDII scanner which can show live data, you can see for yourself whether it is producing an engine RPM. I'm also thinking if it were truly an issue, they wouldn't have passed you. Also, if it is truly an issue, since it's a 2024, it should still be under warranty. Get it to your dealership and have them check it for you.

This sounds like an inspection where the inspectors didn't have professional knowledge of the car.
The RPM signal is available only when the engine is rotating. The engine is rotating when the hybrid system is turned on and:

The battery state is low, or
The engine is cold, or
The accelerator pedal is pressed enough with switch lever in "P" (park)

It sounds like at this stage the engine was no longer cold, and the battery state wasn't low. So it sounds like the inspector didn't understand that as a hybrid car, the engine may be turned off, and to cause it to rotate, the accelerator pedal should be pressed in "P" (park).
Note none of this works in "N" (neutral). In "N" (neutral), it's impossible to start the engine, since the neutral disconnects the current to all electric motors, meaning there's no way to start the engine anymore. A hybrid Toyota doesn't have conventional transmission where neutral disconnects the transmission, a hybrid Toyota has the planetary gearset always connected and the neutral just turns off the current to its electric motors.
What I would do here is to explain to the inspector this procedure the next time you do an inspection. They probably then do the test without pressing the accelerator pedal, notice the "problem" (not a real problem) is there, then re-do the test with pressing the accelerator pedal, notice the "problem" went away, and agree with the theory that it was a misunderstanding and not a real problem.
